# Density of a subset of a dense set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ be a dense set in $[0, 1]$ and let $B\subseteq A$ such that $B$ is not dense in $A$. What can be said about the density of $B$ in $[0, 1]$? Is there any result that may prove that $B$ is/isn't dense in $[0, 1]$?

Comment: Without any information about $B$ apart from $B\subseteq A$, nothing can be said about the density of $B$. For example, if $B=\varnothing$, then $B$ is not dense, and if $B=A$, then $B$ is dense.

Comment: If $A$ is a dense set in $[0,1]$ then $\overline B=A$ is only possible if $A=[0,1].$ That 's because $\overline B$ is a closed set. But maybe "$\overline B=A$ was a typo and you meant $\overline B\supset A?$

Comment: I've edited my question and added that $\overline{B}\ne A$.

Answer (score 3):

By a standard formula for subspace closures:

$$\operatorname{cl}_A(B) = \operatorname{cl}_X(B) \cap A$$

for all $B \subseteq A$. So if $B$ is **not** dense in $A$, $\operatorname{cl}_A(B) \neq A$, so then $A \nsubseteq \operatorname{cl}_X(B)$ and thus $B$ is not dense in $X$ either.

Comment: I think that the formula for subspace closures is valid if $cl_{A}B\subseteq A$. If we don't have this inclusion of sets, is it possible to obtain the same conclusion $(cl_{X}B\ne X)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

If $B$ is not dense in $A$, there is a nonempty open subset $U$ in $A$ (with respect to the subspace topology) which contains no points of $B$.  By definition of the subspace topology, $U = V \cap A$ for some open set $V \subset [0,1]$.  Now $V$ is nonempty and contains no points of $B$, so $B$ cannot be dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Since $B$ is not dense in $A$, we can have $A\subset \overline{B}$ or $\overline{B}\subset A$. Is the above argument valid in the first case?